# Python: making QRcodes in Windows

Tags: python, windows, command, external

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to run [this script (gencards.py)](https://github.com/bieber/qrportrait) in Windows, but he says I need to run "the qrencode command". I assume that means [this library](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.html.en), or the more likely the [windows port](http://code.google.com/p/qrencode-win32/).

In the python script, he uses qrencode as so:

```
os.system("qrencode -o .tempqr.png -s 30 -m 0 -l H " + serial)
```

I've installed the windows library via the executable, I added qrcode.exe to PATH, and tried editing gencards.py to use "qrcode" or "qrcode.exe" but I always get

```
'qrcode' is not recognized as an intrnal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows7 x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message means that Windows does not know what to do with `qrcode`. Check if it's installed in your system, and if it's directory is included in your `PATH` environment variable

Comment: thank you, this was my problem. I needed to include the **directory** in the PATH, not the _directory\filename.exe_ It's my first day with PATH, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try to break the problem down, by first checking if you can run the programm (btw, is it 'grencode' or 'grcode'?) using a command prompt. If you can't then check your PATH settings again. When you succeeded with the command prompt get back to your python script.